# Google images sometimes terribly slow when using dnsmasq

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

I am the admin of a small LAN of 10+ computers. I've set up a dnsmasq server for DHCP and DNS resolution, and it's working *almost* fine..
My problem is that when I try to use Google images, sometimes it takes ages to show the actual images. I get just the textual part of the page (menus and so on) while the images themselves are shown as the still-loading-white boxes..

When I use the DSL router directly as DNS, the site works fine all the time.

The problem sometimes presents itself with Google maps too.. The map takes ages to load.

Any idea on what I could try to troubleshoot this?

(dnsmasq 2.47 on CentOS 5.2 64bit, our outside connection is an asymmetrical 4Mbps DSL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take tcpdumps of all the traffic going into and out of the dnsmasq box, and compare the timestamps to determine what traffic's being slowed or failing.